# Is there a 'mechanism' to assign stream operation values to a local variable in Java 8?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, criteria-api

I assume the answer is no but wanted to check there isn't an elegant work around.  I want to add an unknown number of subquery operations to a JPA criteriabQuery in a java 8 app and was hoping to do something like this

```
Expression where = null;

where = criteriaBuilder.in(from.get(fieldsList.get(0)... )

fieldsList.stream().skip(1)
.forEachOrdered(i -> where = criteriaBuilder
.and(criteriaBuilder.in(from.get(i)).value(getSubquery(edmEntityType,
entityClass, criteriaBuilder, criteriaQuery, from, i)), where));
```

as I'm referencing a number of locval variables this is a no no and I have used a for loop instead

```
for (int i = 1; i < fieldsList.size(); i++){
    where ... 
}
```

I just wondored if there was a more elegant solution ?

Comment: What's the type of the elements of `fieldsList`?

Comment: Take a look at the reduce functions.

Comment: @Eran fieldsList is a List<String>. I don't think there is a good way of doing a forEach skipping the first element ?  Will do Niko.

Comment: `Expression where = fieldsList.stream() .map(i -> criteriaBuilder.in(from.get(i)).value(getSubquery(edmEntityType,
entityClass, criteriaBuilder, criteriaQuery, from, i))) .reduce(criteriaBuilder::and) .get();`